# Crear un Backup en Visual Studio 2019 atraves de la base de datos SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2019

Quiero realizar un respaldo de mi base de datos en el entorno gráfico y me marca el siguiente error a la hora de ejecutar la función que hace el Backup:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot open backup device 'C:\Users\emman\Documents\Backup\Ventas.bak'. Operating system error 5(Acceso denegado.).
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.'
```

Adjunto el código del Formulario:

Nota: Sesión.user y Sesión.Contraseña pertenecen a una clase, ya que realice un formulario y valide si esos usuarios y contraseñas en realidad están en la base de datos, ya que fue mediante inicio de sesión con autentificación SQL.

```
   string usuario = Sesión.user;
   string contraseña = Sesión.contraseña;

public FormularioBackupRestauración()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonConectar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string cadena = "server=EMMANUEL\\SQLEXPRESS;database=master;User ID=" + usuario + "; Password=" + contraseña;
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = cadena;
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand sql= new SqlCommand("Select name from sys.databases",connection);
            
            SqlDataAdapter adapter= new SqlDataAdapter(sql);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            
            if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count>0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow fila in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                    comboBoxBaseB.Items.Add(fila[0].ToString());

                comboBoxBaseB.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
        string server= "EMMANUEL\\SQLEXPRESS";
        private void buttonRutaB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "SQL Backup files|* .bak";
            saveFileDialog1.FileName =comboBoxBaseB.Text +".bak";

            if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBoxRutaB.Text = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void buttonBackup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string cadena = "server=EMMANUEL\\SQLEXPRESS;database=" + comboBoxBaseB.Text + ";User ID=" + usuario + "; Password=" + contraseña;
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cadena);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"BACKUP DATABASE ["+comboBoxBaseB.Text+"] TO DISK ='"+textBoxRutaB.Text +"'",cn);
            cn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Asegurate de que los valores de **comboBoxBaseB.Text** y demás de la cadena de la conexión tengan el formato que se precise (con ' si toca).

También te aconsejaría revisar la línea de `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Backup database= "+comboBoxBaseB+" to disk ='"+textBoxRutaB+"'", cn);` porque quizás como se indica un par de líneas arriba deberían ser  ** comboBoxBaseB.Text** y **textBoxRutaB.Text**

Comment: El error no es creando el archivo de destino? Suena a que no hay permisos para crearlo en la carpeta de ese usuario.

Comment: Cree un botón para ahi mediante un dialogs crear el archivo y obtener la ruta de guardado, mediante este código:  private void buttonRutaB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "SQL Backup files|* .bak";
            saveFileDialog1.FileName =comboBoxBaseB.Text +".bak";

            if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBoxRutaB.Text = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
            }
        }

Comment: Pero ya al ejecutar el buttonBackup es donde me marca el error

Comment: Como dijo Alfabravo. El detalle es falta de permisos en la carpeta en la cual requieres guardar el .bak

Comment: No se si has tenido en cuenta que el BACKUP DATABASE se ejecuta en el servidor SQL y la ruta del .bak tiene que estar en el mismo PC no en el lado del cliente donde se ejecuta la aplicación, por lo tanto el "device" debe de existir en el PC del SQL Server